# How to handle sessions across different devices?

Tags: php, mysql, ios, session

I'm in the initial stage of building a php/mysql backend that exposes a REST interface to a website and iphone/android/etc devices.

I'm not quite sure what is the 'standard' or 'best practices' for dealing with sessions for multiple devices that use the same account.

Here is my current thoughts on how this would work:

1. I would use MySQL to store sessions for now, with a sessions table like so:

   > id, session_id (hash), user_id (int), created (timestamp), expire (timestamp), device (enum)
2. When a user login via iOS app or android app, I would return a session token in the success json for future api calls to use. Same with the website making an api call.
3. For security purposes, I should regenerate and overwrite the session token if the user re-login, but only for the session_id for that device.
4. I also have an expire column that tells me the expiration of the session so that if I wish, I can create a session that can expire in two weeks and is periodically cleaned by a CRON job.

This seem like a reasonable approach to me, but there are problems if the user uses an iphone and an ipad, or multiple android devices using the same account. Anytime the user logins with one would cause the other to log out.

I noticed instagram didn't invalidate the session even if I login from another iphone.

However, I don't think I can duplicate that behavior unless I never overwrite a session token when a user re-login or keep adding session rows into my session table whenever the user logins from the iphone?

What is the standard way of handling sessions across different devices?

Comment: You could always store some extra info with each session such as browser and IP address - only clear sessions that have matching details like that when they log in somewhere new.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would highly discourage you from using mysql to store sessions. I would suggest using redis or memcache. Redis will store the data to disk in case your server crashes. Redis also allows you to set a TTL to expire the session, which would solve #4.

If you are using rest based calls, I would suggest just adding the session to the header as a cookie and pass that back and forth. Basically emulating the way a browser would access that page. I think that would make testing easier too.

Answer (score 2):

Well it seems what you are looking for is not what most would traditionally call "sessions", which is something typically limited to a single browser or client instance.

It seems you are talking more about attaching application state to the user login.  In which case, I don't see why you would have a need for a separate session table/token system.  You would simply use your typical client-side methods of persisting a login, and then when that logged in client contacts your API, you would return application "session" state information, regardless of what actual client instance you are talking to.

This is not to say you wouldn't want to use some sort of token exchange system to give users "fresh" tokens in a case that you wanted to purge their state after a certain period of inactivity, just that you could have multiple active tokens per login.