# How to handle sessions in backend across different devices?

Tags: php, mysql, session, persistence

I have looked through [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12205470/how-to-handle-sessions-across-different-devices), but I really didn't get an answer for what is the standard for handling sessions if I am storing them in a "MySql table". What should actually be stored into a session row, so that I can distinctly identify sessions from different devices. I read the answer saying persisting a login from the client side, that can be done.

But:

1. I don't want to logout all the devices when there's a logout action from one of them, this means I would really have to store different active sessions for the same account.
2. What can be the item which I can actually stored in the backend to distinguish the devices. I don't prefer storing the IPAddress and also there is browser fingerprinting, even they are not 100%.

You can give me suggestions on how to handle them in different rows or how actually should this be handled. And If you are suggesting not to use MySql for this, can you be please more elaborate?

Comment: What is the client? is it a web browser? an app?

Comment: Why not a session ID?  That is how sessions normally work, a unique session ID is stored as a cookie in the client's browser.  This would distinguish each device..

Comment: @cmorrissey: It is a web browser.

Comment: @Devon: Yes, that's a nice idea, I will try that, thanks, but you see, I don't want to logout! if one device logs out

Comment: If you don't want to log out when one device logs out, create a session per each device. Store user's device info in a separate table with session ids.

Comment: @Nordenheim: Yes, I am asking the same question! what is that device Information?, browsers don't have any unique id.

Comment: You assign the unique id for each device.  Call it devices_session_id if you want.  In your back end, devices_session_id only points to a users_session_id (shared by all devices of that user).  All the app-state is associated with users_session_id.  When a device signs-off, all you do is delete that devices_session_id (and keep users_session_id and its state values).

Comment: @Devon: I realize your point now, there will be different cookies for different browsers, because there will different sessions for them, so when I log out, only the corresponding session is destroyed! Thanks :)

Comment: @BareNakedCoder: I got the above idea, what I wrote for Devon, from your answer. Thank you :)

Comment: How do you handle this when app is mobile as well as web ?

Comment: @jitenshah: like said in the above comments, store a unique token in each client. That token could be the id of a row of your session. Recognize the request in the API based on what token is passed along with the request.