# Saving data into session or localstorage

Tags: vue.js, session, e-commerce

So probably every **e-commerce** site has a feature like if you add products to your cart it will be existed everywhere weather its in your phone or computer or tab.I know how to store data in session but when I jump into another device I can't see my cart products available though I use the same account.So please can anyone tell me how to store data in session or local storage that won't be removed by jumping device and will be changed when the user's state changes.I am trying to do that by using vuejs.I will be very glad if you give a solution based on **vuejs**.Thanks..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle sessions across different devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12205470/how-to-handle-sessions-across-different-devices)

Comment: Here is a similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12205470/how-to-handle-sessions-across-different-devices